# Перевод текста из объекта файла в текст

Tags: python, текст, перевод

имею такую прогу

```
files_name = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt']
redacted_file = open('final.txt', 'w+', encoding='utf-8')
xxx = []

for i in range(len(files_name)):
    with open(files_name[i], encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for j in f:
            xxx.append((files_name[i], len(list(f)) + 1, f))


xxx.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

for j in range(len(xxx)):
    redacted_file.write(str(xxx[j][0]) + '\n')
    redacted_file.write(str(xxx[j][1]) + '\n')
    redacted_file.write(str(xxx[j][2]) + '\n')
```

Вот что получается в final.txt

```
> 2.txt 1 <_io.TextIOWrapper name='2.txt' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>
> 1.txt 8 <_io.TextIOWrapper name='1.txt' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>
> 3.txt 9 <_io.TextIOWrapper name='3.txt' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>
```

Все правильно, остается только объекты файла перевести в текст, что тут можно сделать?

Comment: что означает "перевести объекты файла в текст"? Если нужен текст из файла, то и добавляй в список текст из файла, предварительно его прочитав, а не объект ``f``

Comment: `xxx.append((files_name[i], len(list(f)) + 1, f))` - в последнем элементе если нужно добавить весь текст файла, из файла нужно его прочитать: `f.read()`

Comment: Да и мне кажется `list(f)` может сломать итерирование `for j in f:`, лучше так не делать, даже если и не сломает. Непонятно, что нужно то в итоге? Прочитайте файл один раз, а потом уже делайте с ним что хотите - считайте длину и т.д. по прочитанному, а не по самому файлу.

Comment: Спасибо, коллеги!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное, имелось в виду следующее:

```py
for name in files_name:
    with open(name, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        text = f.read()
        xxx.append((name, len(text) + 1, text))
```

Вы итерируетесь по `f` одновременно и через `for` и через `list` уже внутри `for`, так лучше не делать - итерация может сломаться. Ну, разве что если вы хотите так пропустить первую строку файла, но и тогда лучше это по-другому делать, в явном виде как-то.